# does the f-string convert an integer to a string?

Tags: python, string, concatenation, f-string

Hello I was practicing using loops and I saw that while using concatenation I have to convert int's to strings, but then I saw that if I use a f-string I dont need convert it to an int.

Here is the code:

```py
# some code up there

average_cost = [total_cost / len(actual_insurance_costs)]

# using a f-string
print(f"Average Insurance Cost: {average_cost} dollars.")

# using concatenation
print("Average Insurance Cost: " + str(average_cost) + " dollars.")
```

So does the f-string convert an int into a string?

Comment: Yes, you are printing out string representations of `average_cost`. Please lookup the definition of `f-string` to understand how they work better, it should make your question/idea more clear

Comment: Even if *total_cost* is an integer, the result of the division will give you a float which you then "wrap" in a list for reasons that are unclear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does, by way of calling [`format(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#format) on it, which in turn calls `__format__()` on the object.

That extends to everything else too, including objects with a custom [`__format__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__). For instance,

```
class Thing:
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return f"I don't like being formatted with {format_spec!r}!"


print(f"This is a thing: {Thing():>10}")
```

prints out

```
This is a thing: I don't like being formatted with '>10'!
```

(The default implementation of `__format__()` just calls `__str__()`.)

Comment: Link to the description of this in the PEP: https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#code-equivalence